# Can't fetch soft deleted records in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

### What are you doing?

I'm trying to return all active student addresses and soft deleted ones

Here are the three models involved:

````
```js
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Students = sequelize.define('Students', {
    studentIdentification: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    schoolId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Schools',
          key: 'id'
        }
    },
    classificationTypeId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          references: {
            model: 'ClassificationTypes',
            key: 'id',
          }
      },
    zoneId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Zones',
          key: 'id'
        }
    },
    desiredPickUpTime: DataTypes.DATE,
    desiredDropOffTime: DataTypes.DATE,
    createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    deletedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
  }
);
  Students.associate = (models) => {
    Students.belongsTo(models.ClassificationTypes, { foreignKey: 'classificationTypeId'});
    Students.belongsTo(models.Schools, {foreignKey: 'schoolId'});
    Students.belongsTo(models.Zones, {foreignKey: 'zoneId'});
    Students.belongsToMany(models.Companies, {through: 'CompaniesStudents', foreignKey: 'studentId', otherKey: 'companyId'});
    Students.belongsToMany(models.Drivers, {through: 'DriversStudents', foreignKey: 'studentId', otherKey: 'driverId'});
    Students.belongsToMany(models.Addresses, {through: 'StudentsAddresses', as: 'Addresses', foreignKey: 'studentId', otherKey: 'addressId'});
  };

  return Students;
};

```

```js
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Addresses = sequelize.define('Addresses', {
    streetName: DataTypes.STRING,
    streetNameAlt: DataTypes.STRING,
    zipCode: DataTypes.STRING,
    city: DataTypes.STRING,
    town: DataTypes.STRING,
    stateId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'States',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    addressTypeId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'AddressTypes',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    deletedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
  }
);

  Addresses.associate = (models) => {
    Addresses.belongsTo(models.AddressTypes, {foreignKey: 'addressTypeId'});
    Addresses.belongsTo(models.States, {foreignKey: 'stateId'});
    Addresses.belongsToMany(models.Drivers, {through: 'DriversAddresses', foreignKey: 'addressId', otherKey: 'driverId'});
    Addresses.belongsToMany(models.Schools, {through: 'SchoolsAddresses', foreignKey: 'addressId', otherKey: 'schoolId'});
    Addresses.belongsToMany(models.Companies, {through: 'CompaniesAddresses', foreignKey: 'addressId', otherKey: 'companyId'});
    Addresses.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'UsersAddresses', foreignKey: 'addressId', otherKey: 'userId'});
    Addresses.belongsToMany(models.Students, {through: 'StudentsAddresses', as: 'Students', foreignKey: 'addressId', otherKey: 'studentId'});
  };

  return Addresses;
};

```

```js
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const StudentsAddresses = sequelize.define('StudentsAddresses', {
    studentId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    addressId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    deletedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    }
  }, {
    paranoid: true,
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
  return StudentsAddresses;
};
```
````

Here is the api endpoint doing the actionables:

````
    ```js
    export function getStudent(req, res, next) {
  Students.find({
    where: {
      id: req.params.id
    },
    paranoid: false,
    include: [{model: Schools},
              {model: ClassificationTypes},
              {model: Addresses,
                paranoid: false,
                as: 'Addresses',
                include: [{model: AddressTypes,
                           paranoid: false },
                          {model: States,
                          paranoid: false }]
              }
            ]
  }).then((students) => {
    return res.json(students);
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.sendStatus(500);
    next(err);
  });
}
    ```
````

### What do you expect to happen?

*I expect pretty much all records whether soft deleted or not to return*

### What is actually happening?

Im getting back only active records.

````
```js
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import sequelizeConfig from '../sequelize_config';
import { ENV } from '../../../../config/env';
import userModel from './users';
import roleModel from './roles';
import userRoleModel from './userroles';
import stateModel from './states';
import zoneModel from './zones';
import districtModel from './districts';
import holidayModel from './holidays';
import schoolModel from './schools';
import studentModel from './students';
import companyModel from './companies';
import driverModel from './drivers';
import pickupStatusModel from './pickupstatus';
import dropoffStatusModel from './dropoffstatus';
import invoiceStatusModel from './invoicestatus';
import driverStudentActionModel from './driverstudentaction';
import schoolInvoiceModel from './schoolinvoice';
import statusModel from './status';
import schoolMonthlyComplianceModel from './schoolmonthlycompliance';
import privilegeModel from './privileges';
import blockDayModel from './blockdays';
import addressModel from './addresses';
import addressTypeModel from './addresstype';
import classificationTypeModel from './classificationtypes';
import studentsAddressesModel from './studentsaddresses';

const config = sequelizeConfig[ENV];

const db = {};
const dbUrl = process.env[config.use_env_variable];

const sequelize = dbUrl ? new Sequelize(dbUrl) : new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);

db.User = sequelize.import('User', userModel);
db.Roles = sequelize.import('Roles', roleModel);
db.UserRoles = sequelize.import('UserRoles', userRoleModel);
db.States = sequelize.import('States', stateModel);
db.Zones = sequelize.import('Zones', zoneModel);
db.Districts = sequelize.import('Districts', districtModel);
db.Holidays = sequelize.import('Holidays', holidayModel);
db.Schools = sequelize.import('Schools', schoolModel);
db.Students = sequelize.import('Students', studentModel);
db.Companies = sequelize.import('Companies', companyModel);
db.Drivers = sequelize.import('Drivers', driverModel);
db.PickupStatuses = sequelize.import('PickupStatuses', pickupStatusModel);
db.DropoffStatuses = sequelize.import('DropoffStatuses', dropoffStatusModel);
db.InvoiceStatuses = sequelize.import('InvoiceStatuses', invoiceStatusModel);
db.DriverStudentActions = sequelize.import('DriverStudentActions', driverStudentActionModel);
db.SchoolInvoices = sequelize.import('SchoolInvoices', schoolInvoiceModel);
db.Statuses = sequelize.import('Statuses', statusModel);
db.SchoolMonthlyCompliances = sequelize.import('SchoolMonthlyCompliances', schoolMonthlyComplianceModel);
db.Privileges = sequelize.import('Privileges', privilegeModel);
db.BlockDays = sequelize.import('BlockDays', blockDayModel);
db.Addresses = sequelize.import('Addresses', addressModel);
db.AddressTypes = sequelize.import('AddressTypes', addressTypeModel);
db.ClassificationTypes = sequelize.import('ClassificationTypes', classificationTypeModel);
db.StudentsAddresses = sequelize.import('StudentsAddresses', studentsAddressesModel);

Object.keys(db).forEach((key) => {
  const model = db[key];
  if (model.associate) {
    model.associate(db);
  }
});

export { db as Models, sequelize };
```
````

Im using postgres 10, with the latest version of sequelize. This problem was still existent in earlier versions of 4.x sequelize as well.

Answer (score 1):

For any lost soul that wants to figure this out, im not sure why i couldnt find it out in the docs ( i guess its embedded somewhere in there) but it would be like this:

```
export function getStudent(req, res, next) {
  Students.find({
    where: {
      id: req.params.id
    },
    paranoid: false,
    include: [{model: Schools},
              {model: ClassificationTypes},
              {model: Addresses,
                as: 'Addresses',
                through: { paranoid: false },
                include: [{model: AddressTypes},
                          {model: States,
                          paranoid: false }]
              }
            ]
  }).then((students) => {
    return res.json(students);
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.sendStatus(500);
    next(err);
  });
}
```

You can use the through option when querying and disable paranoid, along with query many-many tables